# Running function on Sonata Admin List field

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

In my application, backend users can segment frontend members through criteria like age, gender etc. These criteria are saved in a class called `Segment`.

```
AppBundle\Entity\Segment:
type:   entity
table: segments
fields:
    id:
        id: true
        type:   integer
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
    name:
        type:   string
        length: 300
    created_at:
        type:   datetime
    updated_at:
        type:   datetime
        nullable: true
oneToMany:
    parameters:
        targetEntity: SegmentFilter
        mappedBy:   segment
        cascade: [persist]
manyToOne:
    owner:
        targetEntity:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumn:
            created_by:
                referencedColumnName:   id
```

The SegmentFilter class holds the parameters for filtering the members eg. criteria can be 'age', 'description' can be null but its for clarity purposes for whoever is reading the criteria and finally value can be '>= 30'

```
AppBundle\Entity\SegmentFilter:
type:   entity
table: segment_filters
fields:
    id:
        id: true
        type:   integer
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
    criteria:
        type:   string
        length: 50
    description:
        type:   string
        length: 300
    value:
        type:   string
        length: 300
manyToOne:
    segment:
        targetEntity:   Segment
        inversedBy: paramemters
        joinColumn:
            segmentation_id:
                referencedColumnName:   id
```

Here's the member's class to be segmented based on the parameters defined for each segment:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Member:
type: entity
table: members
fields:
    id:
        id: true
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
    first_name:
        type:   string
        length: 20
    last_name:
        type:   string
        length: 20
    mobile:
        type:   string
        length: 11
    address:
        type:   string
        length: 255
    zip:
        type:   string
        length: 6
    town:
        type:   string
        length: 25
    email:
        type:   string
        length: 50
    dob:
        type:   date
```

In the list of segments, I would like to add an extra field that shows how many members currently fall in each segment created. How would I go about this?

Comment: Could you post your Segment entity, and your User entity, please ?

Comment: I've added all entities involved to make it clearer.

Comment: Since you have a manyToOne association in your Segment entity, in Twig you can use the 'lenth' filter to count the number of User entities linked to each Segment entity. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html Now, if you want to count how many Users meet the criterias defined in SegmentFilters, I think you'll have to run queries for each one, since there's no association between SegmentFilter and User.

Comment: The multiple filters for a single Segment form the conditions that are used to query the Users that fall under the segment therefore the length filter doesn't apply here.

I know I have to run the queries, where to place them is the question

Comment: In your template, can't you call a controller action where you want to display the number of users ? It would make a lot of queries, though, if you have a lot of Segments/Filters. It's hard to tell without the template file, but I think it's pretty easy to do. Something like that ?

{{ render(controller('YourBundle:Segment:countUsers', { segment: segment.id, segmentFilter: segmentFilter.id })) }}

Comment: Sorry I skipped that part temporarily and just seeing your advice now. I'll try it later and let you know how it went. Thanks